# RealmSwift: Query all objects of same generic type

Tags: swift, realm

I'm having a generic function to save objects to my realm storage. Existing objects in Realm that are not in that list should be deleted. How do I fetch all existing objects of the same type generically?

Here is my current approach:

```
  private func determineOrphans(remoteObjects: [Object])->[Object]?{

    guard let remoteObject = remoteObjects.first else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let localObjects = try? queryObjects(with: type(of: remoteObject) ) else{
        return nil
    }
    let allLocalObjectsSet = Set(localObjects.toArray())
    let objectsToDelete = Array(allLocalObjectsSet.subtracting(remoteObjects))
    logger.info("These \(objectsToDelete.count) objects should be deleted: \(objectsToDelete)")
    return objectsToDelete
}

private func queryObjects<T: Object>(with type: T.Type) throws -> Results<T> {
    return try Realm().objects(T.self)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my generic function for realm objects fetch.

```swift
    import RealmSwift

    func queryObjects<T: Object>(with type: T.Type) throws -> Results<T> {
        let realm = try Realm()
        return realm.objects(T.self)
    }
```

Example of usage if you need an array of models as Realm returns own type Results with lazy loaded objects:

```swift
        do {
            let objects = try queryObjects(with: Model.self).map { $0 }
        } catch {
            print("Can not get Model: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

**Update** here completely generic function of `determineOrphans`:

```swift
    private func determineOrphans<T: Object>(remoteObjects: [T]) -> [T] {
        guard let localObjects = try? queryObjects(with: T.self ) else {
            return []
        }

        let objectsToDelete = localObjects.filter { !remoteObjects.contains($0) }
        logger.info("These \(objectsToDelete.count) objects should be deleted: \(objectsToDelete)")
        return objectsToDelete.map { $0 }
    }
```

Comment: Sure - that way it is possible. But I need a more generic solutions as I do not want to copy this code for every object type. Please see my updated code.